# Headphone jack connection: is this setup safe?

Tags: audio

Is this setup safe for the equipment? And am I going to be able to hear both of the sources?
[image: audio jack connection]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not great - the two output stages will tend to backfeed each other, which MIGHT (depending on design) eat the output transistors in one or both, especially if unpowered.

Too, there's somewhat of a risk of generating a ground loop between the two devices, unless they're both battery powered.

Headphones are cheap. A second set will cost less than that adaptor and set of cables.